# How to use Xpath in Selenium for getting attributes from field 'time'(JAVA)

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I use Java+Selenium for getting attributes value(datetime) and get a problem.

This is my html:

```
<div itemtype="garbage" class="content">
<time itemprop='datePublished' datetime='2016-03-16 22:30:03(my aim)'>abnews.ru 16.03.2016 22:30</time>
```

My code should have a format like:

```
(1) String articleDate = driver.findElement(By.xpath("myCodeHere")).getText();
```

Where my code is

```
div/time/@datetime
```

But in this case i got error:

```
div/time/@datetime' selected an object of type 'class com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomAttr' instead of a WebElement.
```

For example, in case when my code is

```
div/time
```

i got results like: 
    "abnews.ru 16.03.2016 22:30"

Help me anyone, how can i take this information without changing of my code format, i mean(1).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your XPath: `//div/time/@datetime`, HtmlUnit is right to say you're trying to treat an attribute as an element. WebDriver is only concerned with elements and will get confused if you try to match anything else. Once you have your returned `WebElement` you can request any attribute by name. So what you need is:

```
String articleDate = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/time")).getAttribute("datetime");
```

Which should give you: `2016-03-16 22:30:03(my aim)`

Calling `getText()` on the element would give you the visible text: `abnews.ru 16.03.2016 22:30`

You don't need to change from XPath to CSS paths or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
FindElement(By.CssSelector("div time")).GetAttribute("datetime");
```

Try the above cod; I hope this will work for you. Please know me if this is not working.
or:

```
FindElement(By.CssSelector("div time[datetime]")).GetAttribute("datetime");
```

What you have done is, you got the value between `<time>` open and end tag `</time>`.
    abnews.ru 16.03.2016 22:30

"gettext" will give the value between the tag.

"GetAttribute" will the give the value of the attribute.